# Basic test of JSONStream not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonstream

I'm having a look at JSONStream in node.js, and I'm trying the following small app to get a handle on it:

```
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var Stream = require('stream');

var s = new Stream();
s.pipe = function(dest) {
  dest.write('{"foo":1}');
  return dest;
};

var parser = JSONStream.parse(/foo/);
s.pipe(parser).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Unfortunately, when run on the commandline, this doesn't write anything to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `parser` also have a `pipe()` function defined? If not, the line `return dest;` could instead be `return arguments.callee;` so that the chained call to `.pipe(process.stdout)` is not called on `parser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you rewrite your code:

```
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var Stream = require('stream');

var s = new Stream();
s.pipe = function(dest) {
  dest.write('{"foo":1}');
  return dest;
};

var parser = JSONStream.parse();
parser.on('data', function(obj) {
  console.log('obj', obj);
});
s.pipe(parser);
```

The reason you can't pipe the output of `JSONStream.parse()` to `process.stdout` is that `JSONStream` outputs objects, and `process.stdout` only accepts strings (and probably Buffers):

```
> process.stdout.write({ foo : 1 });
TypeError: invalid data
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:612:11)
    ...
```

Comment: This has reminded me why I prefer statically-typed languages... :/

Comment: @thecoop this would have given you a similar error: `process.stdin.pipe(JSONStream.parse()).pipe(process.stdout);`. Don't exactly know why it's not generated in your example.